# Get count of related records in two joined tables

Tags: sql, join

Firstly, I apologize for my English. I want get auctions with count of bids and buys. It should look like this:

```
id | name | bids | buys
-----------------------
1  | Foo  |  4   |  1 
2  | Bar  |  0   |  0
```

I have tables like following:

**auction**:

```
id | name
---------
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
```

**auction_bid**:

```
id | auction_id
---------------
 1 |    1 
 2 |    1
 3 |    1
 4 |    1
```

**auction_buy**:

```
id | auction_id
---------------
 1 |    1
```

I can get numbers in two queries:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(abid.id) AS `bids` FROM `auction` `t` LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON (t.id = abid.auction) GROUP BY t.id 

SELECT *, COUNT(abuy.id) AS `buys` FROM `auction` `t` LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON (t.id = abuy.auction) GROUP BY t.id
```

But when i combined it into one:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(abid.id) AS `bids`, COUNT(abuy.id) AS `buys` FROM `auction` `t` LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON (t.id = abid.auction) LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON (t.id = abuy.auction) GROUP BY t.id
```

It was returning wrong amount (bids as much as buys).

How to fix this and get counts in one query?

Comment: So you're looking for the total bids+buys?

Comment: total bids and total buys for each auction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to count `DISTINCT` abuy and abid IDs to eliminate the duplicates;

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT abid.id) `bids`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT abuy.id) `buys`
FROM `auction` `t` 
LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON t.id = abid.auction_id
LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON t.id = abuy.auction_id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23459/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*,COUNT(abid.id) as bids,buys
FROM auction t LEFT JOIN 
      auction_bid abid ON t.id = abid.auction_id LEFT JOIN
(SELECT t.id, Count(abuy.id) as buys
 FROM auction t LEFT JOIN 
      auction_buy abuy ON t.id = abuy.auction_id 
 GROUP BY t.id) Temp ON t.id=Temp.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    BIDS    BUYS
1   Foo     2       0
2   Bar     1       1
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff41/22).

Comment: Ok, that's working with sample data. But what with this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff41/1 ?

Comment: @andrzej1_1: Updated my answer and fiddle example with your sample data.

Comment: @RagingBull Now working. Your solution is easier, but Joachim Isakason's simplier and more interesting.